# When using the download attribute in HTML5, how do I get the file to save as a .jpg rather than a .html file?

Tags: html

I want users to be able to download an image from my website by clicking a download button

```
  <a href="../assets/assets/styleguide/Consult.jpg" download>
  <button class="btn draw-border">Download</button>
  </a>
```

The filepath is correct, and the download is triggered as I get the usual download popup. Instead of giving the option to download as a .jpg, it asks if I want to download 'Consult.jpg' which is in the .html file type, despite having the .jpg extension.

Anyone know why this is happening, or better yet, how to fix it?

Thanks,
Will

Comment: "The filepath is correct" triple check that. You can force the filename (and thus the extension) by setting a value to `downlad="filename.ext"` but if the server says it's an html response, it's probably because it's not pointing to what you want.

Comment: @Kaiido When I click the filepath in VSCode it opens the image up, unless there is some quirk I don't know about it's correct. I should add the file is on the frontend build so no worries there, I tried to force it as a jpg with download="Consult.jpg" but I'm still getting  a html file.

Comment: Just messed about with the filepath and I still get the HTML error even though it's pointing to nothing. I'm using vue so it's in a navbar component which might lead to a variable filepath

Answer (score 0):

Try again by putting the link inside the button tag and give the download attribute the desired name